# Addition of a python dict value to itself

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm just learning Python and I am stumped on how to concatenate a key value to itself.

For instance this works .....

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dict= {}
for num in range (1,5):
        dict['total']=num

print dict['total']
```

This predictably prints "4" since the value of dict['total'] is being replaced constantly with whatever is in num

What I would like to do is constantly concatenate the value of dict['total'] with each pass ( I don't need the below printed, only included for clarity)..

```
dict['total'] = 1,
dict['total'] = 3,
dict['total'] = 6,
dict['total'] = 10
```

I thought it would be as simple as changing the assignment line from

```
dict['total']=num
```

to

```
dict['total']+=num
```

but that gives me an error.....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./count_loop.py", line 5, in <module>
    dict['total']+=num
KeyError: 'total'
```

I'm going to apologize in advance for what is a remarkably remedial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize you dictionary with default value for a key:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dict= {'total': 0}
for num in range (1,5):
   dict['total'] += num

print dict['total']
```

Answer (score 2):

The word you want is addition: concatenation is what you do with sequences like lists and strings.

While you can initialize your `dict` up front, this only works if you know in advance all the keys you're going to use. The naive version of a more flexible solution is:

```
try:
    d['total'] += num
except KeyError:
    d['total'] = num
```

but a simpler and better one is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for num in range (1,5):
    d['total'] += num
```

When you ask for a key and it doesn't exist yet, the defaultdict just creates it with a default value instead of failing. It calls the argument we gave, and `int()` gives zero.

Comment: Another variation:  `d['total'] = d.get('total', 0) + num`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the expected output of the code you give is 10.

In that case, you simply need to initialize `dict['total']` before your loop:

```
dict= {'total': 0}
for num in range (1,5):
        dict['total'] += num

print dict['total']
```

When you’re doing `dict['total'] += num`, it’s like `dict['total'] = dict['total'] + num`, which will obviously throw an error on the first pass of the loop since `dict['total']` hasn’t been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `defaultdict`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(int)
for num in range (1,5):
    dic['total'] += num

print dic['total']
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works and leads to the desired output please?

Comment: @ArcturusB When the key is not in the dictionary, the constructor of the object is called to intialize with the default value. Here the constructor is `int()` as the dictionary is a `defaultdict(int)` so if the dictionary does not contain the key, the value is initialized by `int()` which is 0. See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Why does what you tried not work? On the first iteration of your loop, the `+=` syntactically expands to

```
dict['total'] = dict['total'] + 1
```

Certainly, on the right hand of this equation, a value for dict['total'] has not yet been defined.

You can solve your problem as @FilipMalczak references by initializing a value for key `total` before iterating:

```
dict = {'total':0}
```